# Compiler/platform handling of buggy std::terminate() handlers

Tags: c++

While reviewing bit of code, I came across a buggy `std::terminate()` handler
that wasn't terminating the program, but returning. Based on the documentation for [`std::set_terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_terminate/), I think this falls within the realms of undefined - or at least implementation defined - behaviour.

Under Linux, and compiled using GCC, I found that cores were being dumped, which implies that some guardian angel was calling abort() or something similar on our behalf.

So I wrote the following test snippet, which confirmed my hunch. It looks like GCC or it's std library does wrap `std::terminate()` handlers so they do terminate the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <dlfcn.h>

// Compile using
// g++ main.cpp -ldl

// Wrap abort() in my own implementation using
// dlsym(), so I can see if GCC generates code to
// call it if my std::terminate handler doesn't.
namespace std
{
    void abort()
    {
        typedef void (*aborter)();
        static aborter real_abort = 0x0;
        if (0x0 == real_abort)
        {
            void * handle = 0x0;
            handle = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "abort");
            if (handle)
            {
                real_abort = (aborter )(handle);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "2. Proof that GCC calls abort() if my buggy\n"
                  << "   terminate handler returns instead of terminating."
                  << std::endl;
        if (real_abort)
        {
            real_abort();
        }
    }
}

// Buggy terminate handler that returns instead of terminating
// execution via abort (or exit)
void buggyTerminateHandler()
{
    std::cout << "1. In buggyTerminateHandler." << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Set terminate handler
    std::set_terminate(buggyTerminateHandler);
    // Raise unhandled exception
    throw 1;
}
```

That a compiler (or library) would wrap `std::terminate()` handlers seems sensible to be, so at a guess I'd assume that most compilers do something along these lines.

Can anyone advise regarding the behaviour on Windows using Visual Studio or OS X using GCC?

Comment: Same thing for the MSCRT, it calls abort() when terminate() returns.

Comment: If a terminate handler returns, the behaviour is undefined. Compilers usually handle it by calling`std::abort`. Rely on it at your own (very real) risk.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant and n.m. I wasn't intending to use this corner case - just curious. Thanks for noting the behaviour for MSCRT.